# What is the CBV equivalent of passing params via kwargs and query strings in a FBV?

Tags: django, django-views

If I want to pass a number of variables via a URL path to a view so that I can use it to look up **more than one** object I have a couple of different ways to do this:

**1. Passing as a key word argument in the URL path**

I can pass a parameter via the url path as a `kwarg` in both FBV and CBV:

```
// Function based view:
path('task/detail/<int:pk>/<int:abc>/', views.task_detail,  name='task_detail')`

// Class based view:
path('task/detail/<int:pk>/<int:abc>/', views.TaskDetailView.as_view()
```

Which is passed in the URL as `mysite.com/task/detail/1/2/`.

In a FBV I can access both `kwargs` to get separate objects via `request`:

```
// Function based view:
def task_detail(request, pk, abc)
    first_object = get_object_or_404(FirstObjectModel, id=pk)
    second_object = get_object_or_404(SecondObjectModel, id=abc)
```

**2. Passing as a query string in the URL path**

Alternatively I can pass the parameter via a query string, which is parsed and parameters are stored as a `QueryDict` in `request.GET`, for example `mysite.com/task/detail/?pk=1&abc=2`.

I can then access these via both FBV and CBV as:

```
// Function based view:
def task_detail(request):
    first_object_id = request.GET.get('pk')
    second_object_id = request.GET.get('abc')
    first_object = get_object_or_404(FirstObjectModel, id=pk)
    second_object = get_object_or_404(SecondObjectModel, id=abc)
```

**What is the classed base view equivalent of each of these approaches? Why and when should I use `kwargs` over `query strings`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class based views you can get keyword arguments from the URL from `self.kwargs`, and values from the querystring with `self.request.GET`.

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Use kwargs from URL
        context['first_object'] = get_object_or_404(FirstObjectModel, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['second_object'] = get_object_or_404(SecondObjectModel, id=self.kwargs['abc'])
        # Fetch from GET params
        context['first_object'] = get_object_or_404(FirstObjectModel, id=self.request.GET.get('pk'))
        context['second_object'] = get_object_or_404(SecondObjectModel, id=self.request.GET.get('abc'))
        return context
```

Often, you'll customise a specific class based view, to decrease the amount of code you have to write. For example, you could use a DetailView (used to display an object), then add the second object to the context.

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    model = FirstObjectModel
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['second_object'] = get_object_or_404(SecondObjectModel, id=self.kwargs['abc'])
        return context
```

The decision to include keyword arguments in the URL path/querystring is separate to whether you use function-based or class-based views. In Django, you would usually see URLs like `/tasks/55/` instead of `tasks/?id=55` because they are "cleaner". Querystrings are often used for filtering e.g. `/tasks/?status=complete`.

The class based generic views that create/display/update/delete individual objects expect the slug/primary key to be in the URL path, not the querystring. You can use the querystring to fetch the object, but in that case you need to write more code, e.g. override `get_object`.

Comment: thanks, a very comprehensive answer. So there are no performance or security differences, it's just style/convention between using the two methods?